# Facebook authentication get email id as well

Tags: facebook, authentication

I have successfully access user public profile using following code. I want access email as well using scope. Please help. Here is my code.

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: '<?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>',
      cookie: true,
      xfbml: true,
      oauth: true
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      window.location.reload();
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
      window.location.reload();
    });
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

Comment: You have to do the login. Nothing in that code does login

Answer (score 0):

There's a guide in the Facebook docs on how to setup Facebook Login with the JS SDK:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.1

You might want to check that.